# Apply tint filter to object with code in Animate CC

Tags: createjs, easeljs, animate-cc

I'm using Animate CC 2015 and publishing to Canvas.
Can anyone tell me how to apply a tint to an object on my timeline?
The object has been placed there manually and has an instance name. I simply want to change it from white to red using code that runs in the first frame.

On a related note, do you know of a good JS language reference for Animate CC? I always seem to end up on Actionscript references or the CreateJS site which doesn't cater well for stuff that is created manually on the timeline.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied a tint already in Animate? Filters in Canvas are particularly expensive, so by default, Animate will cache items that have filters applied. You have a few options:

1. Every frame, cache the symbol again. This can be very expensive, but it will work.
2. Instead of transitioning a single filter, cross-fade between a filtered and non-filtered object. This looks very similar (especially with a tint), and has no performance concerns.

As for JavaScript reference, what exactly are you looking for? Mozilla's MDN reference tends to be the goto place for our team when it comes to raw JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Cheers.

Comment: I want to be able to do it all dynamically. I am building a load of files that pull in a config object from an external JS file I want to be able to specify a colour in this file and have Animate apply that colour to an object on the timeline. I don't need to animate the filter, just apply it.

Comment: In terms of a reference I'm after a list of all the objects available in Animate and the methods and properties available on them. So far it seams that the createJS page is best but it is not great to use though I'm perhaps just being picky because I'm being forced to use Animate on a job that would be much better off being hand coded.